# What is the use of app:layout_constrainedWidth in a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am trying to see examples of the use of `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` in a ConstraintLayout, but I am not undesrtanding the use of this attribute. In what ocasions should I use this attribute set to true?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 13):

`app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`  makes *ConstraintLayout* respect the constraints of a view with a width of `wrap_content'. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#wrap_content-:-enforcing-constraints-added-in-1.1) is a fuller explanation.

> **WRAP_CONTENT : enforcing constraints (Added in 1.1)**
>
> If a dimension is set to WRAP_CONTENT, in versions before 1.1 they will be treated as a literal dimension -- meaning, constraints will not limit the resulting dimension. While in general this is enough (and faster), in some situations, you might want to use WRAP_CONTENT, yet keep enforcing constraints to limit the resulting dimension. In that case, you can add one of the corresponding attribute:
>
> ```
>    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true|false"
>    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true|false"
> ```

Let's say that we have the following layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Left TextView"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="I am a TextVIew with some very long text. How is it going to be handled?"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is displayed as

[image]

As you can see, the right *TextView* text is cut off - the right constraint is not honored. Now let's add `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` to the right *TextView*. Now will see

[image]

The view is still `wrap_content`, but the right constraint is honored.